# How to change column into row in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I tried alot. but could not get expected result.I have a query which is giving me following kind of result

```
sno    name          budget     NameTrim      TravelCost       Expense
    3   Local Expense   12       Expense       NULL            24
    4   Curent Expense  12       Expense       NULL            24
    1   Local Travel    123      Travel        246             NULL
    2   Global Travel   123      Travel        246             NULL
```

but the data should be in following format

```
Travel
    1    Local Travel     123
    2    Global Travel    123
             subtotal =   246

Expense

   3    Local Expenses    12
   4    Current Expe      12
         Subtotal   =     24
```

I am using following query

```
SELECT concat([Segment_0], '-' , [Segment_1], '-' ,[Segment_2]) ,  T2.[AcctName],T5.[Name] , 
  sum(T0.[Debit]) as Actual , sum(T3.[DebLTotal]) as Budget ,
  (case 
when T2.[AcctName] like '%Travel%' then right(T2.[AcctName], 30)
when T2.[AcctName] like '%Expense%' then right(T2.[AcctName],30)
end) as NameTrim 
from JDT1 T0  INNER JOIN OJDT T1 ON T0.[TransId] = T1.[TransId] INNER JOIN OACT T2 ON T0.[Account] = T2.[AcctCode], 
OBGT T3 INNER JOIN BGT1 T4 ON T3.[AbsId] = T4.[BudgId] INNER JOIN OBGS T5 ON T3.[Instance] = T5.[AbsId],OASC T6 
Where  T5.[Name] = 'Main Budget 2015'
Group By concat([Segment_0], '-' , [Segment_1], '-' ,[Segment_2]),  T2.[AcctName],T5.[Name]
```

I am posting here table structure of given query please help me.

```
USE [RCTP_NGO]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[BGT1]    Script Date: 09/Nov/2015 12:35:30 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BGT1](
    [BudgId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Line_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DebLTotal] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [CredLTotal] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [DebSTotal] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [CredSTotal] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [DebRLTotal] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [CrdRLTotal] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [DebRSTotal] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [CrdRSTotal] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [FtrIDRLSum] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [FtrIDRSSum] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [FtrICRLSum] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [FtrICRSSum] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [FtrODRLSum] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [FtrODRSSum] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [FtrOCRLSum] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [FtrOCRSSum] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [MonthPrcnt] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [LineMemo] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Instance] [int] NULL,
    [AcctCode] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [UserSign] [smallint] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [BGT1_PRIMARY] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [BudgId] ASC,
    [Line_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[JDT1]    Script Date: 09/Nov/2015 12:35:30 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[JDT1](
    [TransId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Line_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Account] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [Debit] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [Credit] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [SYSCred] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [SYSDeb] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [FCDebit] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [FCCredit] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [FCCurrency] [nvarchar](3) NULL,
    [DueDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [SourceID] [int] NULL,
    [SourceLine] [smallint] NULL,
    [ShortName] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [IntrnMatch] [int] NULL,
    [ExtrMatch] [int] NULL,
    [ContraAct] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [LineMemo] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Ref3Line] [nvarchar](27) NULL,
    [TransType] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [RefDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [Ref2Date] [datetime] NULL,
    [Ref1] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [Ref2] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [int] NULL,
    [BaseRef] [nvarchar](11) NULL,
    [Project] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [TransCode] [nvarchar](4) NULL,
    [ProfitCode] [nvarchar](8) NULL,
    [TaxDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [SystemRate] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [MthDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [ToMthSum] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [UserSign] [smallint] NULL,
    [BatchNum] [int] NULL,
    [FinncPriod] [int] NULL,
    [RelTransId] [int] NULL,
    [RelLineID] [int] NULL,
    [RelType] [char](1) NULL,
    [LogInstanc] [int] NULL,
    [VatGroup] [nvarchar](8) NULL,
    [BaseSum] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [VatRate] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [Indicator] [nvarchar](2) NULL,
    [AdjTran] [char](1) NULL,
    [RevSource] [char](1) NULL,
    [ObjType] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [VatDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [PaymentRef] [nvarchar](27) NULL,
    [SYSBaseSum] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [MultMatch] [int] NULL,
    [VatLine] [char](1) NULL,
    [VatAmount] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [SYSVatSum] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [Closed] [char](1) NULL,
    [GrossValue] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [CheckAbs] [int] NULL,
    [LineType] [int] NULL,
    [DebCred] [char](1) NULL,
    [SequenceNr] [int] NULL,
    [StornoAcc] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [BalDueDeb] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [BalDueCred] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [BalFcDeb] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [BalFcCred] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [BalScDeb] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [BalScCred] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [IsNet] [char](1) NULL,
    [DunWizBlck] [char](1) NULL,
    [DunnLevel] [int] NULL,
    [DunDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [TaxType] [smallint] NULL,
    [TaxPostAcc] [char](1) NULL,
    [StaCode] [nvarchar](8) NULL,
    [StaType] [int] NULL,
    [TaxCode] [nvarchar](8) NULL,
    [ValidFrom] [datetime] NULL,
    [GrossValFc] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [LvlUpdDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [OcrCode2] [nvarchar](8) NULL,
    [OcrCode3] [nvarchar](8) NULL,
    [OcrCode4] [nvarchar](8) NULL,
    [OcrCode5] [nvarchar](8) NULL,
    [MIEntry] [int] NULL,
    [MIVEntry] [int] NULL,
    [ClsInTP] [int] NULL,
    [CenVatCom] [int] NULL,
    [MatType] [int] NULL,
    [PstngType] [int] NULL,
    [ValidFrom2] [datetime] NULL,
    [ValidFrom3] [datetime] NULL,
    [ValidFrom4] [datetime] NULL,
    [ValidFrom5] [datetime] NULL,
    [Location] [int] NULL,
    [WTaxCode] [nvarchar](4) NULL,
    [EquVatRate] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [EquVatSum] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [SYSEquSum] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [TotalVat] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [SYSTVat] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [WTLiable] [char](1) NULL,
    [WTLine] [char](1) NULL,
    [WTApplied] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [WTAppliedS] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [WTAppliedF] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [WTSum] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [WTSumFC] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [WTSumSC] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [PayBlock] [char](1) NULL,
    [PayBlckRef] [int] NULL,
    [LicTradNum] [nvarchar](32) NULL,
    [InterimTyp] [int] NULL,
    [DprId] [int] NULL,
    [MatchRef] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [Ordered] [char](1) NULL,
    [CUP] [int] NULL,
    [CIG] [int] NULL,
    [BPLId] [int] NULL,
    [BPLName] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [VatRegNum] [nvarchar](32) NULL,
    [SLEDGERF] [char](1) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [JDT1_PRIMARY] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [TransId] ASC,
    [Line_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[OACT]    Script Date: 09/Nov/2015 12:35:30 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OACT](
    [AcctCode] [nvarchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [AcctName] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [CurrTotal] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [EndTotal] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [Finanse] [char](1) NULL,
    [Groups] [nvarchar](8) NULL,
    [Budget] [char](1) NULL,
    [Frozen] [char](1) NULL,
    [Free_2] [char](1) NULL,
    [Postable] [char](1) NULL,
    [Fixed] [char](1) NULL,
    [Levels] [smallint] NULL,
    [ExportCode] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [GrpLine] [int] NULL,
    [FatherNum] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [AccntntCod] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [CashBox] [char](1) NULL,
    [GroupMask] [smallint] NULL,
    [RateTrans] [char](1) NULL,
    [TaxIncome] [char](1) NULL,
    [ExmIncome] [char](1) NULL,
    [ExtrMatch] [int] NULL,
    [IntrMatch] [int] NULL,
    [ActType] [char](1) NULL,
    [Transfered] [char](1) NULL,
    [BlncTrnsfr] [char](1) NULL,
    [OverType] [char](1) NULL,
    [OverCode] [nvarchar](8) NULL,
    [SysMatch] [int] NULL,
    [PrevYear] [char](1) NULL,
    [ActCurr] [nvarchar](3) NULL,
    [RateDifAct] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [SysTotal] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [FcTotal] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [Protected] [char](1) NULL,
    [RealAcct] [char](1) NULL,
    [Advance] [char](1) NULL,
    [CreateDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [UpdateDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [FrgnName] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [Details] [nvarchar](254) NULL,
    [ExtraSum] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [Project] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [RevalMatch] [char](1) NULL,
    [DataSource] [char](1) NULL,
    [LocMth] [char](1) NULL,
    [MTHCounter] [int] NULL,
    [BNKCounter] [int] NULL,
    [UserSign] [smallint] NULL,
    [LocManTran] [char](1) NULL,
    [LogInstanc] [int] NULL,
    [ObjType] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [ValidFor] [char](1) NULL,
    [ValidFrom] [datetime] NULL,
    [ValidTo] [datetime] NULL,
    [ValidComm] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [FrozenFor] [char](1) NULL,
    [FrozenFrom] [datetime] NULL,
    [FrozenTo] [datetime] NULL,
    [FrozenComm] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [Counter] [int] NULL,
    [Segment_0] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [Segment_1] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [Segment_2] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [Segment_3] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [Segment_4] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [Segment_5] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [Segment_6] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [Segment_7] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [Segment_8] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [Segment_9] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [FormatCode] [nvarchar](210) NULL,
    [CfwRlvnt] [char](1) NULL,
    [ExchRate] [char](1) NULL,
    [RevalAcct] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [LastRevBal] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [LastRevDat] [datetime] NULL,
    [DfltVat] [nvarchar](8) NULL,
    [VatChange] [char](1) NULL,
    [Category] [int] NULL,
    [TransCode] [nvarchar](4) NULL,
    [OverCode5] [nvarchar](8) NULL,
    [OverCode2] [nvarchar](8) NULL,
    [OverCode3] [nvarchar](8) NULL,
    [OverCode4] [nvarchar](8) NULL,
    [DfltTax] [nvarchar](8) NULL,
    [TaxPostAcc] [char](1) NULL,
    [AcctStrLe] [nvarchar](2) NULL,
    [MeaUnit] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [BalDirect] [nvarchar](4) NULL,
    [UserSign2] [smallint] NULL,
    [PlngLevel] [nvarchar](2) NULL,
    [MultiLink] [char](1) NULL,
    [PrjRelvnt] [char](1) NULL,
    [Dim1Relvnt] [char](1) NULL,
    [Dim2Relvnt] [char](1) NULL,
    [Dim3Relvnt] [char](1) NULL,
    [Dim4Relvnt] [char](1) NULL,
    [Dim5Relvnt] [char](1) NULL,
    [AccrualTyp] [char](1) NULL,
    [DatevAcct] [int] NULL,
    [DatevAutoA] [char](1) NULL,
    [DatevFirst] [char](1) NULL,
    [SnapShotId] [int] NULL,
    [PCN874Rpt] [char](1) NULL,
    [SCAdjust] [char](1) NULL,
    [BPLId] [int] NULL,
    [BPLName] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [SubLedgerN] [nvarchar](60) NULL,
    [VATRegNum] [nvarchar](32) NULL,
    [ActId] [nvarchar](210) NOT NULL,
    [ClosingAcc] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [PurpCode] [nvarchar](2) NULL,
    [RefCode] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [U_COR_FIN_Cls] [nvarchar](32) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [OACT_PRIMARY] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [AcctCode] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[OBGT]    Script Date: 09/Nov/2015 12:35:30 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OBGT](
    [AbsId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AcctCode] [nvarchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [BgdCode] [int] NULL,
    [FatherCode] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [FthrPrcnt] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [DebLTotal] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [CredLTotal] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [DebSTotal] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [CredSTotal] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [DebRLTotal] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [CrdRLTotal] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [DebRSTotal] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [CrdRSTotal] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [FtrIDRLSum] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [FtrIDRSSum] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [FtrICRLSum] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [FtrICRSSum] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [FtrODRLSum] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [FtrOCRLSum] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [FtrODRSSum] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [FtrOCRSSum] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [FinancYear] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Instance] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UserSign] [smallint] NULL,
    [SCNCounter] [smallint] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [OBGT_PRIMARY] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [AbsId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[OJDT]    Script Date: 09/Nov/2015 12:35:30 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OJDT](
    [BatchNum] [int] NULL,
    [TransId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [BtfStatus] [char](1) NULL,
    [TransType] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [BaseRef] [nvarchar](11) NULL,
    [RefDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [Memo] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Ref1] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [Ref2] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [int] NULL,
    [LocTotal] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [FcTotal] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [SysTotal] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [TransCode] [nvarchar](4) NULL,
    [OrignCurr] [nvarchar](3) NULL,
    [TransRate] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [BtfLine] [int] NULL,
    [TransCurr] [nvarchar](3) NULL,
    [Project] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [DueDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [TaxDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [PCAddition] [char](1) NULL,
    [FinncPriod] [int] NULL,
    [DataSource] [char](1) NULL,
    [UpdateDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [CreateDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [UserSign] [smallint] NULL,
    [UserSign2] [smallint] NULL,
    [RefndRprt] [char](1) NULL,
    [LogInstanc] [int] NULL,
    [ObjType] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [Indicator] [nvarchar](2) NULL,
    [AdjTran] [char](1) NULL,
    [RevSource] [char](1) NULL,
    [StornoDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [StornoToTr] [int] NULL,
    [AutoStorno] [char](1) NULL,
    [Corisptivi] [char](1) NULL,
    [VatDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [StampTax] [char](1) NULL,
    [Series] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [Number] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AutoVAT] [char](1) NULL,
    [DocSeries] [smallint] NULL,
    [FolioPref] [nvarchar](4) NULL,
    [FolioNum] [int] NULL,
    [CreateTime] [smallint] NULL,
    [BlockDunn] [char](1) NULL,
    [ReportEU] [char](1) NULL,
    [Report347] [char](1) NULL,
    [Printed] [char](1) NULL,
    [DocType] [nvarchar](60) NULL,
    [AttNum] [int] NULL,
    [GenRegNo] [char](1) NULL,
    [RG23APart2] [int] NULL,
    [RG23CPart2] [int] NULL,
    [MatType] [int] NULL,
    [Creator] [nvarchar](155) NULL,
    [Approver] [nvarchar](155) NULL,
    [Location] [int] NULL,
    [SeqCode] [smallint] NULL,
    [Serial] [int] NULL,
    [SeriesStr] [nvarchar](3) NULL,
    [SubStr] [nvarchar](3) NULL,
    [AutoWT] [char](1) NULL,
    [WTSum] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [WTSumSC] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [WTSumFC] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [WTApplied] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [WTAppliedS] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [WTAppliedF] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [BaseAmnt] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [BaseAmntSC] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [BaseAmntFC] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [BaseVtAt] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [BaseVtAtSC] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [BaseVtAtFC] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [VersionNum] [nvarchar](11) NULL,
    [BaseTrans] [int] NULL,
    [ResidenNum] [char](1) NULL,
    [OperatCode] [char](1) NULL,
    [Ref3] [nvarchar](27) NULL,
    [SSIExmpt] [char](1) NULL,
    [SignMsg] [ntext] NULL,
    [SignDigest] [ntext] NULL,
    [CertifNum] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [KeyVersion] [int] NULL,
    [CUP] [int] NULL,
    [CIG] [int] NULL,
    [SupplCode] [nvarchar](254) NULL,
    [SPSrcType] [int] NULL,
    [SPSrcID] [int] NULL,
    [SPSrcDLN] [int] NULL,
    [DeferedTax] [char](1) NULL,
    [AgrNo] [int] NULL,
    [SeqNum] [int] NULL,
    [ECDPosTyp] [char](1) NULL,
    [RptPeriod] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
    [RptMonth] [datetime] NULL,
    [U_HOF_APPROVAL] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [U_Project] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [U_Site] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [U_Prepared] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [U_Serial] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [OJDT_PRIMARY] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [TransId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BGT1] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_BGT1_Line_ID]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Line_ID]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BGT1] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_BGT1_Instance]  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [Instance]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[JDT1] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_JDT1_Line_ID]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Line_ID]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[JDT1] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_JDT1_IntrnMatch]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [IntrnMatch]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[JDT1] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_JDT1_ExtrMatch]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [ExtrMatch]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[JDT1] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_JDT1_TransType]  DEFAULT ('-1') FOR [TransType]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[JDT1] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_JDT1_RelTransId]  DEFAULT ((-1)) FOR [RelTransId]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[JDT1] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_JDT1_RelLineID]  DEFAULT ((-1)) FOR [RelLineID]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[JDT1] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_JDT1_RelType]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [RelType]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[JDT1] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_JDT1_LogInstanc]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [LogInstanc]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[JDT1] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_JDT1_AdjTran]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [AdjTran]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[JDT1] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_JDT1_RevSource]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [RevSource]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[JDT1] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_JDT1_ObjType]  DEFAULT ('30') FOR [ObjType]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[JDT1] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_JDT1_MultMatch]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [MultMatch]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[JDT1] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_JDT1_VatLine]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [VatLine]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[JDT1] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_JDT1_Closed]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [Closed]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[JDT1] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_JDT1_LineType]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [LineType]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[JDT1] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_JDT1_SequenceNr]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [SequenceNr]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[JDT1] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_JDT1_IsNet]  DEFAULT ('Y') FOR [IsNet]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[JDT1] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_JDT1_DunWizBlck]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [DunWizBlck]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[JDT1] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_JDT1_DunnLevel]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [DunnLevel]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[JDT1] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_JDT1_TaxType]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [TaxType]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[JDT1] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_JDT1_TaxPostAcc]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [TaxPostAcc]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[JDT1] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_JDT1_ValidFrom]  DEFAULT ('19000101') FOR [ValidFrom]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[JDT1] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_JDT1_MIEntry]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [MIEntry]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[JDT1] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_JDT1_MIVEntry]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [MIVEntry]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[JDT1] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_JDT1_ClsInTP]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [ClsInTP]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[JDT1] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_JDT1_CenVatCom]  DEFAULT ((-1)) FOR [CenVatCom]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[JDT1] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_JDT1_MatType]  DEFAULT ((-1)) FOR [MatType]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[JDT1] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_JDT1_PstngType]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [PstngType]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[JDT1] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_JDT1_ValidFrom2]  DEFAULT ('19000101') FOR [ValidFrom2]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[JDT1] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_JDT1_ValidFrom3]  DEFAULT ('19000101') FOR [ValidFrom3]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[JDT1] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_JDT1_ValidFrom4]  DEFAULT ('19000101') FOR [ValidFrom4]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[JDT1] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_JDT1_ValidFrom5]  DEFAULT ('19000101') FOR [ValidFrom5]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[JDT1] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_JDT1_WTLiable]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [WTLiable]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[JDT1] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_JDT1_WTLine]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [WTLine]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[JDT1] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_JDT1_PayBlock]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [PayBlock]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[JDT1] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_JDT1_InterimTyp]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [InterimTyp]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[JDT1] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_JDT1_Ordered]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [Ordered]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_Finanse]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [Finanse]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_Budget]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [Budget]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_Frozen]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [Frozen]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_Postable]  DEFAULT ('Y') FOR [Postable]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_Levels]  DEFAULT ((2)) FOR [Levels]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_CashBox]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [CashBox]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_GroupMask]  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [GroupMask]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_RateTrans]  DEFAULT ('Y') FOR [RateTrans]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_TaxIncome]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [TaxIncome]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_ExmIncome]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [ExmIncome]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_ActType]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [ActType]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_Transfered]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [Transfered]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_BlncTrnsfr]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [BlncTrnsfr]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_OverType]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [OverType]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_SysMatch]  DEFAULT ((-1)) FOR [SysMatch]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_PrevYear]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [PrevYear]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_Protected]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [Protected]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_RealAcct]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [RealAcct]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_Advance]  DEFAULT ('Y') FOR [Advance]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_RevalMatch]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [RevalMatch]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_DataSource]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [DataSource]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_LocMth]  DEFAULT ('Y') FOR [LocMth]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_LocManTran]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [LocManTran]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_LogInstanc]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [LogInstanc]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_ObjType]  DEFAULT ('1') FOR [ObjType]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_ValidFor]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [ValidFor]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_FrozenFor]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [FrozenFor]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_Counter]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Counter]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_CfwRlvnt]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [CfwRlvnt]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_ExchRate]  DEFAULT ('Y') FOR [ExchRate]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_VatChange]  DEFAULT ('Y') FOR [VatChange]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_TaxPostAcc]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [TaxPostAcc]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_BalDirect]  DEFAULT ('0') FOR [BalDirect]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_MultiLink]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [MultiLink]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_PrjRelvnt]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [PrjRelvnt]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_Dim1Relvnt]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [Dim1Relvnt]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_Dim2Relvnt]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [Dim2Relvnt]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_Dim3Relvnt]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [Dim3Relvnt]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_Dim4Relvnt]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [Dim4Relvnt]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_Dim5Relvnt]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [Dim5Relvnt]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_AccrualTyp]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [AccrualTyp]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_DatevAutoA]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [DatevAutoA]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_DatevFirst]  DEFAULT ('Y') FOR [DatevFirst]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_SnapShotId]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [SnapShotId]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_PCN874Rpt]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [PCN874Rpt]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_SCAdjust]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [SCAdjust]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OBGT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OBGT_Instance]  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [Instance]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OJDT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OJDT_BtfStatus]  DEFAULT ('O') FOR [BtfStatus]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OJDT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OJDT_TransType]  DEFAULT ('-1') FOR [TransType]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OJDT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OJDT_PCAddition]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [PCAddition]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OJDT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OJDT_DataSource]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [DataSource]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OJDT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OJDT_RefndRprt]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [RefndRprt]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OJDT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OJDT_LogInstanc]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [LogInstanc]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OJDT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OJDT_ObjType]  DEFAULT ('30') FOR [ObjType]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OJDT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OJDT_AdjTran]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [AdjTran]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OJDT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OJDT_RevSource]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [RevSource]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OJDT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OJDT_AutoStorno]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [AutoStorno]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OJDT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OJDT_Corisptivi]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [Corisptivi]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OJDT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OJDT_StampTax]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [StampTax]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OJDT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OJDT_Series]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Series]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OJDT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OJDT_AutoVAT]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [AutoVAT]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OJDT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OJDT_BlockDunn]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [BlockDunn]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OJDT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OJDT_ReportEU]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [ReportEU]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OJDT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OJDT_Report347]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [Report347]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OJDT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OJDT_Printed]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [Printed]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OJDT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OJDT_AttNum]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [AttNum]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OJDT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OJDT_GenRegNo]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [GenRegNo]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OJDT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OJDT_AutoWT]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [AutoWT]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OJDT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OJDT_ResidenNum]  DEFAULT ('1') FOR [ResidenNum]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OJDT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OJDT_DeferedTax]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [DeferedTax]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OJDT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OJDT_ECDPosTyp]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [ECDPosTyp]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OJDT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OJDT_U_HOF_APPROVAL]  DEFAULT ('Pending') FOR [U_HOF_APPROVAL]
GO
```

Comment: first thing only tag which dbms are you using. mysql or sqlserver? second thing dont include real dbname. it is not good practice.

Comment: i tagged already if you check carefully @rajeshmpanchal

Comment: okay that's good. might be my net is slow.

Comment: Travel and Expense are two table?

Comment: No .. this is data. actually if the data is related to 'Travel' then it should be under travel title with subtotal, if its related to expenses then under Expenses with subtotal and so on.. as i mention in question  @NguyễnHảiTriều

Comment: too much information :)

Comment: do you think this table structure will helpful us to create such table?

Comment: atleast this can help you for executing query

Answer (score 0):

Your code look like:

```
SELECT *,
   CASE WHEN NameTrim = 'Travel' THEN SUM(budget) OVER() ELSE NULL END AS TravelCost,
   CASE WHEN NameTrim = 'Expense' THEN SUM(budget) OVER() ELSE NULL END AS Expense
FROM (
   SELECT CONVERT(INT, T2.budget) AS budget, -- budget is char type, must convert to use SUM
      CASE
         when T2.[AcctName] like '%Travel%' then 'Travel'
         when T2.[AcctName] like '%Expense%' then 'Expense'
         end as NameTrim 
   FROM JDT1 T0
      INNER JOIN OJDT T1 ON T0.[TransId] = T1.[TransId]
      INNER JOIN OACT T2 ON T0.[Account] = T2.[AcctCode]
      CROSS JOIN OBGT T3
      INNER JOIN BGT1 T4 ON T3.[AbsId] = T4.[BudgId]
      INNER JOIN OBGS T5 ON T3.[Instance] = T5.[AbsId]
      CROSS JOIN OASC T6 
  WHERE T5.[Name] = 'Main Budget 2015'
) AS A
```

Comment: this query giving me Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'when'. please check again . @Nguyễn Hải Triều

Comment: can you please show me by adding it into given query properly. because when i used it . it giving me so many errors , might be i use wrongly. please add in given query. so that it would clear to me.

Comment: cAN you please change your changes in given query . please. I am struggling with this query.. please help out

Comment: Not found table: `OBFS` and `OASC`

Comment: hows its possible? there should be OBSC table and OASC..Please wait.. give me 5 mins..let me create script one time more. please

Comment: now i am getting  Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 18
The column 'BatchNum' was specified multiple times for 'A'.

Comment: Because two table is sample column name. Get one of them.

Comment: Nguyễn Hải Triều There is the value Sum(T3.DblTotal) instead of sum(budget) in first line.if i use this value its giving unknown coulmn.because its T3 table is inside the sub select statement.. please check original query written in question. and please add here. I am unable to handle this thing. please help

Comment: Ok, please give me 5 mins

Comment: OBGT is T3 which not includes column: DblTotal.

Comment: i am not getting you . which two tables? please refer the orignal query from question and change it accordingly. so that it could work. @Nguyễn Hải Triều

Comment: There is OBGT. please have a look in query written in question carefully.. everything is there @Nguyễn Hải Triều

Comment: But I don't see table `OBGS ` in your sample create data. 
Your code: `INNER JOIN OBGS T5 ON T3.[Instance] = T5.[AbsId]`
And: `OASC T6`. I don't see this table

Comment: please wait. i am telling you..stay here please

Comment: you are talking about script yea? or query?

Comment: Script and Query not match! In query you inner join table `OBGS` and table `OASC`. But in script create data, I don't see them

Comment: I mean, I want to test in your data :)

Comment: yes i got your point. i am going to update script again .wait few mns please..its in processing  @Nguyễn Hải Triều

Comment: i am not able to paste my script .. because of more than 30000 character. is there any other way to give you that script. if you have email. if its possible.? this solution of this query is urgent for me. and i am just frustrated for this,.. please help me out how can i give you?

Comment: nguyenhaitrieuga@gmail.com. Please notice me when you sent

Comment: What are tables contain return columns? sno, name, budget? Example: sno is in T1 table, name is in T2 table,...

Comment: sorry.. which tables you talking about? please brief? @Nguyễn Hải Triều

Comment: Your result contains sno, name, budget? There are in where table?
Sorry, my bad eng

Comment: the one which i posted . that is just an example. but in query . there are different fields. like AcctName,AcctCode etc. if you check  @Nguyễn Hải Triều

Comment: please check mail. i expained here everything

Comment: i am getting Could not allocate space for object '<temporary system object: 422217137455104>' in database 'tempdb' because the 'PRIMARY' filegroup is full. Create disk space by deleting unneeded files, dropping objects in the filegroup, adding additional files to the filegroup, or setting autogrowth on for existing files in the filegroup.